# Finite special orthogonal groups over the dyadic rationals.

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory

The special orthogonal group $SO_n (\mathbb{Z})$ is finite for all $n$. For which dimensions $n$, if any, is the special orthogonal group over say the dyadic rationals $SO_n (\mathbb{Z}[1/p])$ finite?

Suppose that $T$ is a matrix in $SO_n (\mathbb{Z}[1/p])$ and write its entries in the form $[T]_{ij} = \frac{m_{ij}}{2^{n_{ij}}}$ so that $2 \nmid m_{ij}$. Then the orthonormality condition forces $m_{ij} \leq 2^{n_{ij}}$. If one could bound $m_{ij}$ irrespective of the $n_{ij}$ then that'd be enough to say the group was finite (since then the $n_{ij}$ could neither get too large nor too small). But I'm not sure if that can be done or not.

I'd appreciate any pointers. Thanks.

Comment: You write $\mathbb{Z}[1/p]$, but since you speak of the "dyadic rationals", are you only interested in the case where $p=2$?